# Create predicate on Date field for Hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast, predicatebuilder

Does anyone know how to create the date type predicate for Hazelcast?
I use `Predicates.equal("date","value");` It doesn't work properly. I pass an existing date value in Hazelcast. It returns nothing. `java.util.date` should be comparable. 
I don't know why it doesn't compare properly. Anybody can help, appreciate very much!

Comment: Maybe different timezones or milliseconds or something? It should work, same as using SQLPredicate.

Comment: are you using it with the first parameter as a string with attribute name? are you sure you are comparing exactly same date? java.util date holds milliseconds.

Comment: I'm using it with the second parameter as string in camel. I'm pretty sure comparing the exactly same date. But Hazelcast seems not possibly compare date.

Answer (score 2):

you can also try out your own predicate. i.e. if you have a map with key being Object and value being Date then you can do the following:

```
final Date requiredDate = /*your date object*/;

map.values(new Predicate<Object, Date>() {

public boolean apply(Entry<Object, Date> arg0) {

        Date date = arg0.getValue();

        if(requiredDate.equals(date))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
});
```

you can do other forms of comparisons inside the apply method as well.

Comment: Thanks very much for response. My map structure is that Object is value, and the random string is key. The object has a Date property. And I do date property lookup in blueprint DSL in Camel. The issue is I pass a date formate string to hazelcast, it doesn't get matched result.

Comment: i am not sure if i understood your setup correctly. the object has a Date (java.util.Date) property and in the predicate, you are passing a String (java.lang.String) as the comparable?

Comment: well if this is indeed what you are doing. then dont you think this approach is wrong. you are essentially trying to compare Date with String. i understand that both are comparable but that does not mean both will be able to compare each other. i would suggest that you pass a Date object in your predicate instead of the formatted string.

Comment: I know what you mean. I tried to pass a formatted Date object in. But It's not  working yet. So Hazelcast seems not compare the Date object. That's the issue.

Comment: give my solution in the answer a try. you will be able to debug your code using log statements and breakpoints that way.